Relative error between two transfer functions
I have a system whose transfer function is given by $\frac{\mathbf{b}_1}{\mathbf{a}_1}$. And I have an estimated transfer function model $\frac{\mathbf{b}_2}{\mathbf{a}_2}$. I want to find the relative error between these two models and give it as one numerical value. What is the good approach to compare the transfer functions? Directly finding errors between $\mathbf{b}_1$ & $\mathbf{b}_2$ and $\mathbf{a}_1$ & $\mathbf{a}_2$ may not be a good solution, and so is the approach to compare the poles and the zeros.
Consider a 3rd order Transfer functions:
TF1: $\frac{\sum_{i=0}^3 g_iz^i}{\sum_{i=0}^3 h_iz^i}$ and TF2: $\frac{\sum_{i=0}^3 l_iz^i}{\sum_{i=0}^3 m_iz^i}$.
The vectors: $$\mathbf{b}_1 = \begin{bmatrix}g_3 & g_2 & g_1 & g_0\end{bmatrix}, \mathbf{a}_1 = \begin{bmatrix}h_3 & h_2 & h_1 & h_0\end{bmatrix}$$,
$$\mathbf{b}_2 = \begin{bmatrix}l_3 & l_2 & l_1 & l_0\end{bmatrix}, \mathbf{a}_2 = \begin{bmatrix}m_3 & m_2 & m_1 & m_0\end{bmatrix}$$.
d(1) = designfilt('lowpassiir','DesignMethod','ellip','FilterOrder',3, ... 
'PassbandFrequency',0.5,'PassbandRipple',0.5,'StopbandAttenuation',20);
[b1,a1] = tf(d(1)); 
coeff1 = impz(d(1)); 
tc_est = coeff1(1:20) + 0.001*randn(20,1);
[H,w] = freqz(tc_est,1,20);
[b2,a2] = invfreqz(H,w,3,3); 
sys1 = tf(b1,a1,1); 
sys2 = tf(b2,a2,1); 
bode(sys1,sys2);


What exactly are $b_1$  etc? Scalars, vectors, polynomial coefficients ?

They are vectors containing coefficients of monomials of maximum order $n$ arranged from $n$th-degree to constant.

Probably you should normalize $h_3$ and $m_3$ to 1 by scaling both numerator and denominator of the transfer functions with the same constant.

Quantifying the amount of difference (absolute or relative) of two transfer functions is somewhat complicated and there is no "one size fits all" method.
Comparing the functions in the domain of polynomial coefficients, section coefficients and or poles and zeros is typically not useful. These are just "means to and end" and not the properties we actually care about. In some cases the coefficient sensitivity is VERY high, e.g. moving a pole by a small amount can change the transfer function drastically, in other cases  fairly different poles and zeros can produce very similar results. It's more meaningful to compare the transfer functions directly in the frequency domain. Hence the approach of using invfreqz() to identify poles and zeros seems counterproductive, especially since invfreqz() is numerically not very robust and often runs into stability and noise problems.
Let's say we have two transfer function $H_2(z)$ and $H_1(z)$ where $H_1(z)$ is the "reference". We can sample this at some frequency grid $z = e^{j\omega_k}, k = 0...N-1$ and we end up with two vectors $H_1[k] = H_1(e^{j\omega_k})$ etc.
The choice of frequency grid is the first important decision: could be a linear grid, could be a log grid, could be an FFT grid, could be restricted to a certain frequency band, could include Nyquist and DC or not, etc. That's very dependent on the type of transfer function and the specific application requirements.
Since this is a half-band filter, we'll choose an FFT grid with linear spacing.
The first step is always to take a look both transfer functions.

At first glance these match quite well. One obvious difference is that the reference has zeros at normalized frequencies 0.32 and 0.5 which are not as deep in the approximation. A second difference becomes visible if we zoom in on the notch.

Not only is the notch not as deep it has moved to a slightly lower frequency. This illustrates the problem of coming up with a difference metric: if you are just looking for a generic lowpass filter, the approximation works just fine. If you do indeed need a notch at that exact frequency that goes down all the way to zero, the approximation would be terrible.
We can start with looking at the difference of the two vectors.
$$H_D[k] = H_2[k]-H_1[k]$$
The magnitude looks like this

Visually we can "eyeball" the difference: in the pass band the error is about -40 dB and in the stop band it's maybe -30dB.
We could try to squeeze this into a single number by a simple energy consideration
$$E_1 = \frac{\sum |H_D[k]|^2}{\sum |H_1[k]|^2}$$
which comes out to be $7.25 10^{-5}$ or about -41 dB. This is sort of ok in this case (since the stopband level is only -20dB) but typically NOT a good choice for a lowpass filters. The problem here is that the energy in the passband dominates the energy in the stopband. That means any stopband error will be mostly ignored and you would hardly see a difference between a stopband of -80 dB or -100dB.
The way around this is to apply a frequency dependent weight vector $W[k]$ that "amplifies" the error in the stop band and we get
$$E_2 = \frac{\sum W[k] |H_D[k]|^2}{\sum W[k]|H_1[k]|^2}$$
If we want all frequencies to be equally represented regardless of their absolute value, we can choose a weight of $W[k] = 1/|H_1[k]^2$. If we pop this into the previous equation and rearrange
$$E_3 = \frac{1}{M}\sum \frac{|H_D[k]|^2}{|H_1[k]|^2+\epsilon}$$
here we needed to introduce a "small" constant $\epsilon$ to avoid "divide by zero" problems at frequencies where the reference transfer function is very small or zero. If we set $\epsilon$  to something really small like $10^-10$ we end up with a ridiculously large error. This reflects the fact that the approximation does a very poor job of matching the notches (which may or may not matter to you). The reference has two zeros in the transfer function. At these zeros, the difference is much large than the transfer function itself and this dominates the total error. You can't define a "relative error" to a quantity that is zero so this needs some work around.
Since this is a lowpass filter and if we don't care about the exact shape of the notches, we could make an argument that everything in the stopband is "ok" as long as it is at or below the stopband target level.  A simple way to achieve this would be to set the $\epsilon$  to the stopband level, i.e. $\epsilon= 0.1$. With that we get an error of about -39 dB which seems quite reasonable. This method would also work for much lower stopband levels.
Similar considerations would be applicable to looking at phase and group delay differences and there are other methods based on the ratio instead of the different, but this answer is already too long as it is.
In conclusion: your best shot is to derive a metric from the requirements of the specific application.

I am assuming this is a system identification for a control loop implementation (otherwise further details on the application could be helpful for other considerations).
For this I have used a Bode Plot (frequency response magnitude and phase response) as a comparison of the transfer functions with emphasis of the accuracy of the magnitude and phase up to twice the expected loop BW (beyond that the accuracy of the transfer function is less significant). Small gain errors and small phase errors have a similar significance on total vector error, so a least squares metric of the gain (in magnitude not dB) and phase error (in radians) between the two transfer functions would be a useful single quantity for comparison of relative accuracy.
The OP has updated the post to indicate that the intention is to determine the transfer function from a noisy impulse response. If the goal is to have ideally get the exact same frequency response in both magnitude and phase, with equal significance in match across the entire frequency response, then for that I recommend using the approach I outlined as follows:  Determine the frequency response of both systems (can use the the function ‘freqz’) and then find the complex error versus frequency as the difference between the two responses (complex to captures both mag and phase error assuming both responses are important). Take the magnitude of those errors, square, average and take the square root. That is your total rms error in a least squares sense. Weigh stop band or pass and accordingly if either are more important.
Note: This may be a flawed metric / approach for many reasons including: There could be a phase difference due to a relative time delay between the systems, but otherwise inconsequential to distortion in a processed waveform. An impulse response test is a relatively noisy approach to system identification for continuous-time (analog) systems given the energy constraints of realizable approximations to impulses. Swept sine (network analysis) measurements are much more common. As an alternative to swept sine, I recommend least squares channel estimation using wideband (spectrally rich) sounding patterns that fill the bandwidth of interest as I outline including source code and demonstration in DSP.SE # 63141.

Thank you for your comment. I added a MWE in my post, where I have the true system sys1 and I have a noisy estimate for the initial impulse response of the system. Using this estimate, I find sys2 and now I would like to know the relative error between these two systems.
